# How do I compare values of an Arraylist with string values and a regular array with string values?

Tags: java

I have an arraylist with string values that the user inputs. I have another array but its not an arraylist.  This array has a bunch of string values.  I want to compare both of the arrays to see if the ArrayList has the same string as the array.
The userEnteredWords is the arraylist and the arrayofValidWords is the regular array.

public void wordAddedUserArray()
{

```
    String getInput = anagramWord.getText().toString();

    if(userEnteredWords.contains(getInput)){
        Toast.makeText(AnaGramAttack.this, "Word already added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (getInput == null || getInput.trim().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(AnaGramAttack.this, "Input is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(!Arrays.equals(arrayofValidWords, userEnteredWords)){
        Toast.makeText(AnaGramAttack.this, "OOF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        userEnteredWords.add(getInput);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AnaGramAttack.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, userEnteredWords);
        wordList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
   
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a value exists you should use a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) as they are optimized for lookups. A lookup in a set takes `O(1)` time while it could be `O(n)` in an array. Therefore you should convert your array to a `Set` once and then use that `Set` as often as you need to to check your user supplied lists.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var matchingList = List.of("str1", "str1");
        var notMatchingList = List.of("str1", "strWrong");
        var whitelist = new String[]{"str1", "str1"};

        // create a set of the whitelist
        // this will allow lookups in O(1) time
        var setWhiteList = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(whitelist));

        System.out.println(compare(setWhiteList, matchingList));
        System.out.println(compare(setWhiteList, notMatchingList));
    }

    public static boolean compare(Set<String> whitelist, List<String> listToCheck) {
        // check if all values in the list are in the whitelist
        // if they are not false is returned, if they are true is returned
        return whitelist.containsAll(listToCheck);
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
true
false
```